# Can't update int type column in mysql

Tags: mysql, int

What is wrong with this mysql query?

UPDATE answers SET 23 = 2 WHERE user_id ='1';

I am trying to update an int(2) field, and this just isn't working.

**23 is the name of the column by the way**

Comment: Is 23 the name of your field? Please post your table structure

Comment: yes, 23 is the name of the field

Comment: I'm not sure who to blame more, those who name their columns with numbers or the programmers who allowed happening.

Comment: @Mladen: Please share with us a condition that you have in your code with something like `WHERE \`23\`+\`4\`=\`42\` `

Answer (score 6):

If `23` is your column name then escape it using `` ` ``

```
UPDATE answers 
SET `23` = 2 
WHERE user_id ='1';
```

Comment: No, 23 is the column name, but I want it to happen where user_id = 1

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the column you try to update is called `value`, you should use code like the following:

```
UPDATE answers SET value = 2 WHERE user_id ='1' and value='23';
```

**EDIT**

With respect to this comment:

> yes, 23 is the name of the field – Mladen

```
UPDATE answers SET `23`= 2 WHERE user_id ='1';
```

This should be the correct query. However, you should not use just numbers as column names, for the reason you just encountered: MySQL might confuse them with the number-identifier with a real number and thus your queries might fail.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE answers SET [23] = 2 WHERE user_id ='1';
or 
    UPDATE answers SET `23` = 2 WHERE user_id ='1';
```

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be

```
UPDATE answers SET <column_name> = 2 WHERE user_id ='1';
```

Answer (score 0):

If `23` is the name of your field, then you need to escape it this way:

```
UPDATE answers SET `23` = 2
WHERE user_id ='1';
```

That's because it is not interpreting it as a a field but rather as a number.

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d96fa/3)

Hope that helps.